# I have used layer masks in GIMP

Tags: save, mask, layer, gimp

After using layer masks, what do I need to do to export the final image?  Do I delete, merge or flatten or none of these things?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Not appropriate topic for StackOverflow. (the title is also poor, though that could be easily fixed.)

Answer (score 0):

If using the UI, you just export, this will export a visual equivalent of the canvas.

If writing a script, what you export with the `file-save-*` calls is a single layer, so you can use `layer-new-from-visible` to create that new layer before exporting it (and then remove it).